# Cant mount windows phone 8 with kubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows, 14.04, kubuntu, phone, dolphin

I am trying to mount my **windows phone 8** with my **Kubuntu 14.04** but I can not get access to it. I have mounted my phone in **Fedora 20** with **Gnome 3.10** and **Ubuntu 13.10** but it not seem possible with Dolphin.

Comment: Does the windows phones use the MTP that androids use or is it something all together different? There seems to be MTP package in the ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my Lumia 1520 mounts on Ubuntu 14.04, if I restart the phone, while having it connected to my pc.

Comment: I found easy way...plug in your phone to laptop or PC.then log out your session and log back in.it mounts.it worked for me.i hope it will work for others.